# MSSQL with nginx on AWS EC2 having RHEL

Tags: sql-server, nginx, amazon-ec2, yum, rhel

I would want to connect my Laravel application to an SQL Server. Locally, it's all fine and perfect.
However following same steps on AWS EC2 does not give the required result.
Instead I am stuck with 'Could not find driver' exception on launching the application. Here are a few parameters to be considered.
And yes, have tried all solutions I could find.

1. Using yum for the EC2 environment
2. nginx and not apache is used
3. PHP version is 5.6.11
4. RHEL version is 7.1

Need your help please